# Can't insert background image html/css

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem inserting a background to my website.

I use this css formatting:

```
<body background='imgs/papBG.png' bgproperties='fixed'>
    <img src="Imgs/banner.png" width="100%">
    <div id='cssmenu'>
        <ul>
            <li class='active'><a href='index.html'><span>Página Inicial</span></a></li>
            <li><a href='#'><span>Shows</span></a></li>
            <li><a href='#'><span>Blog</span></a></li>
            <li><a href='#'><span>Loja do Fã</span></a></li>
            <li><a href='#'><span>Perguntas Frequentes</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id='budy'>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </div>
```

```
#budy {
        width:1000px;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        border-left-style:solid;
        border-right-style:solid;
        border-width:3px;
        background-image: url('imgs/budyBG.png'); /* add quotes, still not working */
        border-bottom-style:solid;
        font-family: Corbel;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
        background-repeat:repeat; /* edited, still not working */
    }
```

And this is the result and I can't find the why of this...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycryZ.jpg

Or this is some kind of bug or I am blind and can't see where I'm mistaking.

EDIT: added some more code so you guys can understand the website better

Comment: what is the issue in the screen shot you're showing us? there appears to be a background image in multiple places

Comment: You can only use `background-repeat` once, your second declaration is overwriting the first.

Comment: background-image: url('imgs/budyBG.png');

add quotes. More, the problem it's not clear (however second background-repeat rule it's overwriting first one)

Comment: can you share a fiddle for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check to make sure your background image is loaded. Sometime I write the wrong image URL and it looks like that.

Answer (score 0):

you should set the background to the body itself to get the same result as in the picture you attached

```
body{
    margin:0;    
    background-image: url(imgs/budyBG.png);
    border-bottom-style:solid;
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
```

Comment: That's not what I'm trying to do, I'm trying to put another different background to the Budy which is the part of the website where you can see a left and right border.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            width:1000px;
            height:400px; /* Leave out the <br>'s */
            margin:0 auto;
            border:3px solid #000;
            border-top:0;
            background-image:url('imgs/budyBG.png');
            background-repeat:repeat
            font-family:'Corbel';
            border-radius:0 0 15px 15px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#budy {
        width:1000px;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        border-left-style:solid;
        border-right-style:solid;
        border-width:3px;
        background-image:url("img_tree.png");
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        border-bottom-style:solid;
        font-family: Corbel;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
        background-repeat: repeat;
    }
```